# How the uart implemented in lin module in autosar, or how to configure the LIN to be used as uart ..?

Tags: autosar

We are trying to utilize the Uart as per the new requirements, but lin driver supports only the master mode in the configuration, my doubt is how to use the autosar lin driver for uart purposes, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The AUTOSAR MCAL does not support UARTs, except hidden behind LIN and so on.

Some MCU vendors offer Complex Device Drivers, which make the functionality available in AUTOSAR projects.

In worst case, you have to implement one yourself.